# Euclidean black hole extrinsic curvature

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, curvature, event-horizon

I have read that the extrinsic curvature at the horizon of a euclidean black hole is zero?  Does anybody know how this can be shown?

Comment: Not sure how to answer your question fully, but since the horizon is two dimensional, there are two normals with respect to which extrinsic curvatures can be defined.  If $n$ is one of the normals, the ext. curvature for that direction is $\mathcal{L}_ng_{\mu\nu}$ and so vanishes if $n$ is a Killing vector for your metric.  In your Euclidean case this Killing property is what you'd need to show presumably.

Comment: @twistor59: I'd probably define the horizon to be the "stack" of two dimensional horizons along the null tangent, which would be a 3-d null surface in the static case.

Comment: @twistor59: Would you Explain the relationship between extrinsic curvature defined here and the mean curvature?

Comment: I'm agree with @twistor59. At the horizon the normal vector and Killing vector coincide, then the Lie derivative of normal vector which by definition is called extrinsic curvature, will vanish. By the way I think it is not necessary to the horizon be two dimensional.